# Update a single cell in an Excel spreadsheet using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm just wondering how to update a single cell in an excel spreadsheet with Pandas in a python script. I don't want any of the other cells in the file to be overwritten, just the one cell I'm trying to update. I tried using .at[], .iat[], and .loc() but my excel spreadsheet does not update. None of the other deprecated methods like .set_value() work either. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd

tp = pd.read_excel("testbook.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1")
tp.at[1, 'A'] = 10
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Have you re-saved the updated file after updating? Once updating in pandas, you need to write it back to the disk, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: are you saving your modified df to excel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might suggest using xlwings for this operation, as it might be easier than reading and writing a sheet in pandas dataframes. The example below changes the value of "A1".

```
import xlwings as xw

sheet = xw.Book("testbook.xlsx").sheets("Sheet1")
sheet.range("A1").value = "hello world"
```

Also note xlwings is included with all Anaconda packages if you're using that: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html

Comment: Thank you so much!! Been searching for ages for this solution! All the other solutions require reading and writing which ruins the format of all my cells! This simply updates the single given cell without touching anything else and replacing other sheets! Bravo!